# Unable to create a pod with extended resources advertised on a node

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Hello i have a single node cluster where i have advertised the extended resource named "sctrls" to the node softserv1141 by following the docs at [kubernetes-extended-resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/extended-resource-node/). Over here i ran the command:

```
kubectl get nodes -o yaml
```

for which the output contained the following part which means the resource creation was successful.

```
status:
addresses:
- address: 172.16.250.120
  type: InternalIP
- address: softserv1141
  type: Hostname
allocatable:
  cpu: "3"
  ephemeral-storage: "7721503937"
  hugepages-1Gi: "0"
  hugepages-2Mi: "0"
  memory: 16163880Ki
  pods: "110"
  sctrls: "64"
capacity:
  cpu: "3"
  ephemeral-storage: 8182Mi
  hugepages-1Gi: "0"
  hugepages-2Mi: "0"
  memory: 16266280Ki
  pods: "110"
  sctrls: "64"
```

I tried creating assigning the extended resource to a pod and creating it by following the docs at [kubernetes-assign-extended-resource-pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/extended-resource/).
the pod file is as follows

```
$ cat nginx-pod.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: extended-resource-demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: extended-resource-demo-ctr
    image: nginx
    resources:
      requests:
        sctrls: 3
```

I got the following problem during pod creation

```
$ kubectl create -f nginx-pod.yaml 
The Pod "extended-resource-demo" is invalid: 
* spec.containers[0].resources.limits[sctrls]: Invalid value: "sctrls": must be a standard resource type or fully qualified
* spec.containers[0].resources.limits[sctrls]: Invalid value: "sctrls": must be a standard resource for containers
* spec.containers[0].resources.requests[sctrls]: Invalid value: "sctrls": must be a standard resource type or fully qualified
* spec.containers[0].resources.requests[sctrls]: Invalid value: "sctrls": must be a standard resource for containers
```

I dont know why i am getting this error and havent found any good solution to this online. But i feel it might be the kubectl version as the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/extended-resource/) mention this as a feature state : Kubernetes v1.18 [stable] where as my kubectl version is

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.8", GitCommit:"ec6eb119b81be488b030e849b9e64fda4caaf33c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-12T21:00:06Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.8", GitCommit:"ec6eb119b81be488b030e849b9e64fda4caaf33c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-12T20:52:22Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I need to confirm if that is the problem or there is an untested solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this paragraph from the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/extended-resource/#assign-an-extended-resource-to-a-pod) has the answer: "Extended resources are fully qualified with any domain outside of *.kubernetes.io/. **Valid extended resource names have the form example.com/foo** where example.com is replaced with your organization's domain and foo is a descriptive resource name.".